# Find coefficient of ordinary generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I'm having a hard time understanding how to find the coefficient of a generating function. I'm working through the example from my book (as shown in the photo). I see the answer is C(18, 15) - C(4,1)*C(12,9) + C(4,2)*C(6,3) and I understand why we care about the coefficient of C(18,15)  or (x^15) but why do we want to subtract and add the coefficients from these other terms specifically? Why wouldn't the answer just be C(18,15)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the following we use $\binom{n}{k}:=C(n,k)$ to denote the binomial coefficient $n$ choose $k$. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{27}]&\left(x^3+x^4+\cdots+x^8\right)^{4}\\
> &=[x^{27}]x^{12}\left(1+x+\cdots+x^5\right)^{4}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{15}]\left(1+x+\cdots+x^5\right)^{4}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^{15}]\left(1-x^6\right)^4\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)^4\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^{15}]\left(1-\binom{4}{1}x^6+\binom{4}{2}x^{12}-\binom{4}{3}x^{18}+\binom{4}{4}x^{24}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot
> \left(1+\binom{4}{1}x+\binom{5}{2}x^2+\binom{6}{3}x^3+\cdots\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=[x^{15}]\left(1-\binom{4}{1}x^6+\binom{4}{2}x^{12}\right)\cdot
> \left(1+\binom{4}{1}x+\binom{5}{2}x^2+\binom{6}{3}x^3+\cdots\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\left([x^{15}]-\binom{4}{1}[x^9]+\binom{4}{2}[x^3]\right)\cdot
> \left(1+\binom{4}{1}x+\binom{5}{2}x^2+\binom{6}{3}x^3+\cdots\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=\binom{18}{15}-\binom{4}{1}\binom{12}{9}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{3}\tag{7}\\
> &=816-4\cdot220+6\cdot20\\
> &=56
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $x^3$ and since we have to take the forth power we get $x^{12}$.
- In (2) we use the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we apply Theorem 2.2.1 of the book. This theorem effectively uses the summation formula for a *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*

  \begin{align*}
  1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
  \end{align*}

  here with $n=5$ and it also uses the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* with $\alpha =-4$ to obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{(1-x)^4}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-4}{n} (-x)^n\\
  &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+3}{n}x^n\\
  &=1+\binom{4}{1}x+\binom{5}{2}x^2+\binom{6}{3}x^3+\cdots
  \end{align*}

  Putting all together we get the right hand side of (3)
  \begin{align*}
  \left(1+x+\cdots+x^5\right)^{4}&=\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^4\\
  &=\left(1-x^6\right)^4\left(1+\binom{4}{1}x+\binom{5}{2}x^2+\binom{6}{3}x^3+\cdots\right)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we expand both, polynomial and series.
- In (5) we observe that powers $x^{18}$ and $x^{24}$ of the polynomial do not contribute anything to $[x^{15}]$ and can so be safely skipped.
- In (6) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply again the rule as we did in (2).
- In (7) we select the coefficients of $[x^{15}], [x^9]$ and $[x^3]$ of the series and obtain the representation in the book.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Your answer help me a lot, I didn't think I could understand how to solve this type of advanced problem, but now I learn it from your superb answer!

Comment: @IsanaYashiro: Great! Good to see the answer is useful. :-) Many thanks for your kind remark.